# Не уходит почта с сервера, куда копать?

Tags: email, sendmail, ispmanager, exim, exim4

Есть сервер у Hetzner, стоит ISPmanager 6, домен подключен через CloudFlare, почта настроена по инструкции с официального сайта. Входящие письма приходят, а исходящие просто копятся в очереди Exim. При попытке принудительно отправить письмо из очереди команда подвисает минут на 10 и так же ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге оказалось, что Hetzner блокирует 25ый порт для VPS. Для разблокировки из панели управления надо подать запрос.